# Failure rate of communication protocol stopping after 2 consecutive erroneous frames

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expected-value

> Given a communication channel that transfers frames which are $n_{bits}=160$ bits long with a $l_{CRC}=32$ CRC checksum at the end of each frame. The CRC has a hamming distance of $h=6$.
>
> This communication protocol goes into a system that has the option of stopping safely if it detects that something is wrong. Thus, the protocol is programmed to stop safely after detecting $c=2$ consecutive erroneous frames. Recognizing $c-1$ frames as erroneous and not considering them is not a big deal because of the high refresh rate and stopping after detecting $c$ consecutive erroneous frames is not considered a failure either because the system can stop safely. A failure happens when a wrong frame is recognized as okay (with a CRC falsely checking the frame as good).
>
> The frame rate is $N=720000$ frames per hour. The error bit rate is $p_e = 10^{-2}$.
>
> What is the failure rate of such a protocol ?

---

The result doesn't have to be algebraic and can be simply computed. Here is my attempt.

Probability of a frame with at least 1 erroneous bit giving a wrong frame :
$$P(\text{wrong frame}) = 1 - (1 - p_e)^{n_{bits}}$$
$$P(\text{wrong frame}) = 0.7997 $$

Probability of a CRC recognized as okay :
$$ P(\text{CRC recognized as okay}) = 2^{-l_{CRC}}$$
$$ P(\text{CRC recognized as okay}) = 2.3283\times10^{-10}$$

Probability of frame with k erroneous bits
$$ P(\text{frame with k erroneous bits}) = \binom{n_{bits}}{k} {p_e}^k(1-p_e)^{(n_{bits}-k)}$$

Probability of wrong frame with h or more erroneous bits
$$ P(\text{wrong frame with h or more erroneous bits}) = 1 - \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{h} P(\text{frame with k erroneous bits}) $$
$$ P(\text{wrong frame with h or more erroneous bits}) = 0.0057 $$

Probability of unrecognized wrong frame
$$ P(\text{unrecognized wrong frame}) = P(\text{CRC recognized as okay})\times P(\text{wrong frame with h or more erroneous bits})$$
$$ P(\text{unrecognized wrong frame}) = 1.3371\times10^{-12} $$

Up to there I am quite sure of the result. It is in the next phase of the computation where has to be taken into account the number of wrong frames tolerated that I have doubts.

Expected value of length of communication :
$$ E(\text{length of communication}) = P(\text{wrong frame})^{-c}$$
$$ E(\text{length of communication}) =  1.5636$$

Probability of unrecognized false frame during the length of communication
$$ P(\text{unrecognized false frame during the length of communication}) = 1 - (1-P(\text{unrecognized wrong frame}))^{E(\text{length of communication})}$$
$$ P(\text{unrecognized false frame during the length of communication}) = 2.0905\times10^{-12} $$
Probability of unrecognized false frame during 1 hour, i.e. failure rate
$$ \Lambda= P(\text{unrecognized false frame during the length of communication})\times\left(\frac{N}{E(\text{length of communication})} \right)$$
$$ \Lambda= 9.6267\times10^{-7}$$

when computed this result isn't a function of the number of false frame tolerated $c$ wich seems odd. Am I on the right track or should I look into conditional probabilities ? It seems to me that the failure rate should be much lower knowing that there are no 2 consecutive wrong frames rather than with an arbitrary number of wrong frames. Thank you for any help.

Comment: What do you consider an erroneous frame?  Your first calculation shows that $0.2$ of all frames have at least one bit error.  If having a bit error, which will make the CRC not match, makes an erroneous frame, you have $0.04$ chance that two successive frames both have errors.  We have not used the power of the CRC.  With a Hamming distance of $6$ you should be able to correct two bit errors and detect three bit errors if you want.  If you have a four bit error you might correct it but not to the intended frame.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your interest in this problem. The first calculation shows that 0.8 of all frames have at least one bit error. Is that right, or did I get the computation wrong? It is weird that most frame are erroneous but we are considering a bad scenario with a bit error rate that high.
If this is right, there is a probability of 0.8*0.8 of 2 consecutive erroneous frames. 
The hamming distance of 6 does offer the possibility of correcting erroneous frames but it is not intended in this protocol to use this possibility.

Comment: Yes, your computation is correct.  It should not be surprising, as the expected number of errors is $1.6$ per frame.  As you say, that is quite high for any reasonable protocol.  It can be overcome with sufficient error correction.  If you are not going to do error correction, why have the information about the CRC in the problem?

Comment: Thank's again for your interest in this question.
Yes I agree the bit error rate is horrendous. As you pointed out, the expected length of communication before 2 consecutive erroneous frames occurs is only 1.6 frames sent.
The idea of choosing such a bad bit error rate is to test the sturdiness of the protocol in a very noisy environment.  We  choose not to do error correction but to stop the communication if the CRC doesn't match. This on its own should make the protocol more robust. This is what i'm trying to prove with this computation.

Comment: It will make the protocol more robust from the point of view of not getting an incorrect message through, but you will rarely get a message through at all.  It depends on how many frames a message is but you will be stopping all the time.  Normally you trade off the chance of getting a wrong message through against the chance of getting the right message through.  Error correction can raise the chance a message gets through considerably.

Comment: Yes, we choose to stop in a safe manor rather correct an erroneous frame. It would be a similar as detecting a noisy environment and choosing to stop safely.

Comment: I realize there is missing context for this question. Sorry about this. I will modify the question to explain this a little more.

Comment: "when computed this result isn't a function of the number of false frame tolerated $c$ wich seems odd" - Not at all. You want to know the probability that an erroneous frame incorrectly passes the CRC check, right? Then how you handle erroneous frames that correctly fail the CRC check does not matter at all. Am I right that you can drop the whole second paragraph except the last sentence?